# how to use ">" or "<" as variable in javafx sqlite query

Tags: sql, sqlite, javafx

I have created a combobox in javafx and I want to query the sqlite db for data which are greater or less than what is selected from the combobox.

Combobox have ObservableList  "10,20,30,40,50"

My query is " Select * From table Where age ( xxx ) ?"

xxx can be (" >=" or "<=")

this is my query

```
String qry_age = "Select * From table Where age (>=) ?";

PreparedStatement ps_age = connect.prepareStatement(qry_age);
ps_age.setInt(1,15);
ResultSet rs_age = ps_age.executeQuery();
while (rs_age.next()) {
System.out.println(rs_age.getString("age"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use string concatenation to construct the query:

```java
String ageCompareOperator = ">="; // or something else e.g. value from ComboBox

String qry_age = "Select * From table Where age " + ageCompareOperator + " ?";

PreparedStatement ps_age = connect.prepareStatement(qry_age);
...
```